# Shouldn't Empty Strings Implicitly Convert to false

Tags: string, d, implicit-conversion, boolean-logic

Why does

```
if (x) {
    f();
}
```

call `f()` if `x` is an empty string `""`?

Shouldn't empty strings in D implicitly convert to `bool` `false` like they do in Python and when empty arrays does it (in D)?

Update: I fixed the question. I had incorrectly reversed the reasoning logic. Luckily, the bright D minds understood what I meant anyway ;)

Comment: why nobody rates the questions up, i don't get it

Comment: @Quonux: First guess: because D is not a scripting language...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Conditions and `if` statements and loops are cast to `bool` by the compiler. So,

```
if(x) {...}
```

becomes

```
if(cast(bool)x) {...}
```

and in the case of arrays, casting to `bool` is equivalent to testing whether its `ptr` property  is not `null`. So, it becomes

```
if(x.ptr !is null) {...}
```

In the case of arrays, this is actually a really bad test, because `null` arrays are considered to be the same as empty arrays. So, in most cases, you don't care whether an array is `null` or not. An array is essentially a struct that looks like

```
struct Array(T)
{
    T* ptr;
    size_t length;
}
```

The `==` operator will check whether all of the elements referred to by `ptr` are equal, but if `length` is `0` for both arrays, it doesn't care what the value of `ptr` is. That means that `""` and `null` are equal (as are `[]` and `null`). However, the `is` operator explicitly checks the `ptr` properties for equality, so `""` and `null` won't be the same according to the `is` operator, and whether a particular array which is empty has a `null` `ptr` depends on how its value was set. So, the fact that an array is empty really says nothing about whether it's `null` or not. You have to check with the `is` operator to know for sure.

The result of all this is that it's generally bad practice to put an array (or string) directly in a condition like you're doing with

```
if(x) {...}
```

Rather, you should be clear about what you're checking. Do you care whether it's empty? In that case, you should check either

```
if(x.empty) {...}
```

or

```
if(x.length == 0} {...}
```

Or do you really care that it's `null`? In that case, use the `is` operator:

```
if(x is null) {...}
```

The behavior of arrays in conditions is consistent with the rest of the language (e.g. pointer and reference types are checked to see whether they're `null` or not), but unfortunately, in practice, such behavior for arrays is quite bug-prone. So, I'd advise that you just don't ever put an array by itself in the condition of an `if` statement or loop.

Answer (score 4):

the default conversion of arrays looks at the `.ptr`, which means only the default initialized arrays (or explicitly set to null) evaluate to false

as an added effect string literals in D are `\0` terminated which means `("")[0] == '\0'` and as such `("").ptr` can't be null (which would lead to a segfault)

IMO it should look at the length and you can use the ptr when you need to

Answer (score 3):

It does when I try it...

```
void main() {
    import std.stdio;
    string s = "";
    if(s)
            writeln("true"); // triggered
}
```

If it was "string s = null;" (which is the default initialization), it doesn't, because the null converts to false, but "" is ok on my computer. Are you sure it isn't null?

BTW, if you want to test for (non-)emptiness, the way I prefer to do it is if(x.length) and if(x.length == 0). Those work consistently for both "" and null, then if you specifically want null, do if(x is null). It is just a little more clear, especially since "" and null are interchangeable in a lot of other contexts in D.

Comment: I thought empty non-null strings also implicity converted to `false`. I always think that a type instance containing no information should implicit-convert to `false`. Just out of curiosity...in what cases do you want such a behaviour?

Comment: It is because of the pointer - Jonathan's answer went into more detail on this. Why would you want it? eh, idk, I never use if(x). Sometimes I do want to know if it was null or not - think of a case where null means the user never entered any information, and "" means they completed the form, but purposefully left it blank. That's sometimes useful. But if(x) is just kinda weird, so I prefer if(x is null) to check that exactly.

Comment: Ok. I buy that, `null` maps to "undefined" and `""` to zero/empty.